# How to make a text file have the same layout when fetched and added to a div

Tags: javascript

I'm still pretty new to coding and I've just started using Fetch and Ajax and to practice Im building an application that fetches a txt file of a book from a local folder and displays it on the web page in a div.

The issue I'm having is that the text file which I have structured to be easily readable is coming out as one pure block of text.

This is what I have right now without stringify or split or splice:

```js
function getText() {
  fetch('aliceinwonderland.txt')
  .then(function(response){
    return response.text();
  })
  .then(function(myBook) {
    let text = myBook;
    document.getElementById('book_section').innerHTML = text
  })
}
```

I looked at json.stringify which gives me the text block but also makes the newlines (\n) visible and doesn't put the new line.

I also looked at .split and .splice and I am still trying to get these to work but I am sure there has to be a better way to do it.

Really what I need to be happening is for the txt file to be displayed as made in the text file but right now its just a block of text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### white-space

You can use [`white-space: pre;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) in your CSS to honor `\n` characters and other whitespace as formatted in your text file:

```
#book_section {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML will condense any whitespace (spaces, tabs, newlines) into a single space character when displaying content.

There are a few ways to handle this, one way is to replace the newline `\n` characters with `<br>` elements:

```
let text = myBook;
let reformattedText = text.replace("\n", "<br>");
document.getElementById('book_section').innerHTML = reformattedText
```